# Transfer [SPECIFIC] data from sheet1 to sheet2 when condition met

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in transferring required data in a row of data to another sheet instead of just copying the entire row to another sheet.
Example of the sheet1 that i take data from -->
[Excel Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6c7A.jpg)
From the picture, i want to take Data Qty,Description, PartNo and paste it to
[This excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BMuw.jpg)
. Note that the columns are different, Qty can be column H in sheet1 but can be column B in sheet2.
Here is the code i use to copy the whole row.
How can i change it to copy specific data? Please help, im stuck thanks.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim i, LastRow

LastRow = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, “E”).Value = “” Then
Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, “E”).EntireRow.Copy 
Destination:=Sheets(“Sheet2”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by SPECIFIC **precisely**?

Comment: I want to get data from a row, but not the column A TO Z but instead, Getting Column B, D, H datas only.

Comment: What are the columns on Sheet1 you want to transfer and what are the columns on Sheet2 you want to set to?